# PHPExcel import just first worksheet into Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, excel, phpexcel

I have this code I found and it works great except for it imports all the worksheets into my MySql db and I only wnat the first worksheet.

```
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test_db");  
 include ("PHPExcel/IOFactory.php");  
 $html="<table border='1'>";  
 $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('example.xls');  
 foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)   
 {  
  $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();  
  for ($row=2; $row<=$highestRow; $row++)  
  {  
       $html.="<tr>";  
       $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet-     >getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue());  
       $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue());  
       $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_excel(excel_name, excel_email) VALUES   ('".$name."', '".$email."')";  
       mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
       $html.= '<td>'.$name.'</td>';  
       $html .= '<td>'.$email.'</td>';  
       $html .= "</tr>";  
  }  
 }  
 $html .= '</table>';  
 echo $html;  
 echo '<br />Data Inserted';  
 ?>
```

I have tried 
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0); 
as well as getSheet(0); 
and many other things to no avail.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Comment: Then break the loop after first iteration